# What does "be blown upon" mean there?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've looked up several dictionaries but didn't find this phrasal verb actually.

"Well now, and what did you think of Bellair?" he asked.
"Very little indeed." said I.
"I may tell you," continued the judge,"that to me the employment os a fellow like that appears inexplicable. I know him; he knows me too; he has often heard from me in court; and I assure you the man **is** utterly **blown upon**; it is not safe to trust him with a dollar, and here we find him dealing up to fifty thousand. I can't think who can have trusted him, but I am very sure it was a stranger in San Francisco."

(*The Wrecker* by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, chapter x, published 1892)

Comment: Obsolete: has a ruined reputation.

Comment: Blown upon. Made the subject of a scandal. His reputation has been blown upon, means has been the subject of talk wherein something derogatory was hinted at or even asserted. Blown upon by the breath of slander.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Is it a truncated form of "blown upon *by the breath of slander*"?

Comment: Blown upon by something. Scandal, shame, disgrace, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Anything to do with flies laying eggs?

Comment: I had only heard this metaphor used in the opposite extreme as in "whiff of scandal"

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whiff-of-scandal 

But in that context, scandal is not inferred. As in, "He has a righteous reputation; never even whiffed".

Comment: @TimR - One can be _touched_ by scandal. Affected, marked, stigmatised, etc. Who knows where these 1890s informal usages came from?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can't remember where, but I remember reading something like scandal alights upon a person like flies upon festering sores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow_upon) gives the meaning of '*blow upon*' to be

> 1. To defame, discredit; make someone the subject of a scandal.

'*To be blown upon*' means 'discredited' or 'having been subject of a scandal'.

This corresponds with the comments by Michael Harvey. [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/hshdc3a) offers a lot of quotations containing this idiom. For example:

> - "She cried, ‘She was undone, and that the reputation of her house, which was never been **blown upon** before, was utterly destroyed." (Fielding, Henry. *The History of Tom Jones.* 1749.)
> - "As your name is not **blown upon** yet, suppose you coin a couple of quires!" (Foote, Samuel. *The Bankrupt.* 1773.)
> - "‘But I will blow her,’ he said, ‘I will **blow** her ladyship’s conduct in this business!’." (Scott, Walter. St Ronan's Well. 1824.)

The connotation with '[whistleblower](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/whistleblower)' in that last example is probably coincidental (but note the lack of 'upon' there).